# Jquery - bring json object from the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

My server return this simple object from the server as `dataType : "text"` (not json):

```
{
  "width": "100%",
  "callBack" : myCallBack //note! this is a function reference without quotes.
}
```

see bellow, I want to pass the data came back from the server to some lib (that I dont control)

```
 $.ajax({
    url: controller + "/" + action,
    dataType: "text",

    success: function (data) {
      o.jqxGrid(JSON.stringify(data));
     }
 });
```

this is what I have tried:

```
 o.jqxGrid(JSON.stringify(data));//not working
 o.jqxGrid(eval(data));//not working
```

How can I convert the string above to a js object.

**Edit**
by the way, without the "callBack" : myCallBack it is woking fine.
Maybe I should send something else?
Thanks

Comment: `eval('('+data+')');`

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the data your expect back (`console.log(data)`)? Also, what is your reason for returning text and turning it into JSON instead of using `dataType: 'JSON'`? Your return is already JSON...

Comment: @RocketHazmat, thanks, post it as an answer if you want the credit, working fine, thanks (Explanation will be nice)

Comment: `$.parseJSON()` is how you convert the string above to a JS object.

Comment: @Barmar: Not if it's not valid JSON.  P.S. The string here isn't valid JSON.

Comment: just wrap quotes around `myCallback` and send all as json. Can still call the function using `[]` notation

Comment: @SexyMF: I don't really agree with it though, it's not the best answer, just kind of a "workaround".

Comment: @charlietfl: I agree with that.  Make `myCallBack` a string, then do `window[data.callBack]()` (or put the function into another object and use that).

Comment: I agree with all these comments. A web util that requires the client to use `eval` seems poorly designed and potentially dangerous.

Comment: @charlietfl, I dont control the callback invocation. @ all ,it is not a valid json, so only what Rocket Hazmat suggested works, thanks anyway your your help!

Comment: I don't understand last comment...if you are passing this to a plugin as config you can adjust prior to passing the data directly to the plugin

Comment: @charlietfl - can you please explain your last comment? how would you do that?

Comment: create intermedate step and convert string:  `data.callback= window[data.callback]` then pass to `o.jqxGrid`. If callback methods are in another object use that instead of `window`

Comment: That is a nice Idea! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option to do this is to use eval - but that is a horrible idea.

The reason your eval did not work is because you need to surround it with parenthesis.

```
o.jqxGrid(eval('('+data+')'));
```

But using eval on the response data from AJAX is dangerous and error prone and will likely lead to security concerns (you are putting your complete trust on whatever generates that response!).

I would recommend using instead a standard JSON formatted object (without referencing javascript variables) and then decorating that object with your local variables manually. Perhaps you could have special keyword strings to replace.